# Stop navigation back to Fiori Launchpad Home Page after clicking on Home Button

Tags: navigation, sapui5, home-button

I want to check something before navigating back and show a fragment where the user cand decide if he really wants to quit the application and go back to the `Fiori Launchpad` home page, or if he wants to stay in the current application.

I have attached a function to the button

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("homeBtn").attachPress(function(){
....
});
```

and in this function the fragment dialog is opened (which I can only see while debugging), but this doesn't stop the navigation back to the home page.

Does anyone have any idea how I can stop this navigation to the home page, after clicking on the Home Button of the `Fiori Launchpad`?

Comment: good post, would also be interested in it. Currently I did not find a way to prevent the home-button Navigation. Anyone able to help?

Comment: Accessing launchpad controls via `Core.byId` (e.g. `"homeBtn"`) is **not** part of the public APIs! Applications are already breaking because they relied on such solutions: https://answers.sap.com/questions/13627344/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [`preventdefault`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to stop navigating to fiori launchpad in click handler of `a` (*anchor*) tag which you can find by getting respective `DOM` element of home button.

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
onAfterRendering: function() {

    var homeBtn = sap.ui.getCore().byId("homeBtn").getDomRef();

    $($(homeBtn).find("a")).on("click", function(event) {
        // do this if user do not want to navigate to launchpad
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: Accessing launchpad controls via `Core.byId` (e.g. `"homeBtn"`) is **not** part of the public APIs! Applications are already breaking because they relied on such solutions: https://answers.sap.com/questions/13627344/

Comment: I posted this answer 5 years 7 months ago :)

Comment: Yes, my comment is a warning for future readers since this  Q&A is still very much discoverable when googling the issue